# Is there a CUDA equivalent to std::numeric_limits?

Tags: c++, cuda

I would like to determine the maximum `int` value in a CUDA kernel. Unfortunately I can't find anything similar to `std::numeric_limits` for CUDA. Trying to use the `::std` function results in a error:

`error : calling a __host__ function("std::numeric_limits<int> ::max") from a __global__ function("xyz_kernel") is not allowed  C:\cuda.cu(153) (col. 10)`

Is there a way to determine the desired value from withing a kernel, or should I just pass it as a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It exists but it is not as generic as `std::numeric_limits`. See [this page](http://dirac.ruc.dk/manuals/cuda-4.0/NPP_Library.pdf) for the list.

For example, you can have `NPP_MAX_32U` but this is specific to `32-bit unsigned` rather than to the `int` type, whose width is system-dependent.

Comment: Okay thanks. Even though it won't work as expected (system-dependent behavior is intentional), it answers my question.

Comment: NPP is just a (particular, primarily image-processing focused) library within the CUDA ecosystem.  Technically these values are specific to NPP.  There's nothing wrong with using these header-defined quantities in arbitrary code as long as you include the npp header file and understand what the values mean.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, Very good point. I should have checked more carefully.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Would like your input on my answer, if you can spare the time.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbles across this now, the following is now standard in CUDA:

```
#include <cuda/std/limits>
float value = ::cuda::std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written something like that:

#### [CUDA-compatible version of `<limits>` (named `limits.cuh`](https://gist.github.com/eyalroz/858d7beae1ad09b83b691107306d0176))

Essentially this means adding `__host__ __device__` to a bunch of functions, and putting all of the structures within a namespace other than `std`.

Notes:

1. Licensing. It's based on `<limits>` from libstdc++, so GPL with the standard library exception.
2. This has undergone some, but not extensive, testing, with device-side code (only).
3. There may be some macro clashes with the actual `<limits>` (I'm not sure).

Comment: Instead of adding `__host__ __device__` to every `constexpr` function, you can just pass `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` to `nvcc`. See http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský: That is, indeed, possible, but it means forcing you to always build that way. Perhaps that's not a bad idea though.